# jQuery.on() both self and children

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, selector, jquery-on

The `.on()` method in jQuery will either match on the matched element if no selector is provided or only on it's children if ther is a selector.

Is it possible to combine these two behaviours to end up with a single .on() statement that matches both the element and any specified children?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mwvdlee/YFF2k/

Answer (score 2):

You can simply bind the event handler to the parent and use [`event.target` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) to the get actual target element of the event:

```
$('.foo').on('click', function(event) {
    console.log('click', event.target);
});
```

Since events bubble up (that's how event delegation works in the first place), every click on a descendant of `.foo` will trigger the event handler of `.foo` (unless the event was stopped somehow of course).

Answer (score 0):

By default the events are bubbling up. Just avoid passing a delegate `selector` and attach the event-handler on the parent. When children will get clicked, the event should bubble up to the parent and the event will get fired.

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/YFF2k/2/**

```
$('.foo').on('click', function (e) {
    console.log('click', e.target);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like:

```
$('.foo').children().andSelf().on('click', function (event){
  //something
});
```